# I want to convert 28*28 pixel to 32*32 pixel of image

Tags: python, image-processing, pixel

I have Mnist dataset. This dataset has 70,000 row and 785 column which one of column is class.
For example, how to convert 28*28 pixel values to 32*32 pixels using first row pixel variable ?

[my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JGzF.png)

Comment: you will first need to load your dataset into pandas or numpy. then you can reshape your 1D vector into 2D and add a 2 pixel frame to convert the pictures from 28x28 to 32x32. After that reshape your 2D matrix back to a 1D vector. Why do you want the picures to be 32x32. do you have a pretrained model that works only with 32x32 pictures?

Comment: No, i do not have any pretrained model.

Comment: the why you want the images to be 32x32?

Comment: Because it is  my homework.

Comment: ok, then my first comment explains the steps you need to do.